# Julia: efficient parallelization of dissimilarity matrix computation

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

The Julia language supports parallelization through methods like pmat() and @parallel.

I am trying to compute a dissimilarity matrix for a set of data:

```
n = length(dataset)
mat = zeros(n,n)
for i = 1 : n
    for j = i+1 : n
        mat[i,j] = mat[j,i] = f_dist(dataset[i], dataset[j])
    end
end
```

Since the calculations are independent, I figure this should be a good candidate for parallel computation.

My attempt at using pmat() and @parallel both ended up being slower.

```
mat = @parallel (+) for comb in collect(combinations([1:n],2))
    submat = zeros(n,n)
    i = comb[1]
    j = comb[2]
    dist = f_dist(dataset[i],dataset[j])
    submat[i,j] = dist
    submat[j,i] = dist
    submat
end
```

I understand that @parallel is a bad way to go because I am essentially creating a bunch of sparse matrices and adding them together. Very inefficient.

Is there an efficient way to get this to work? I've tried SharedArrays and DistributedArrays but haven't figured out how to do what I want.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With SharedArrays it should be fairly straightforward: this code is straight out of my head and not tested, but something like

```
mat = SharedArray(Float64, n, n)
combs = collect(combinations([1:n],2))
chunkbreaks = linspace(0, length(combs), nworkers()+1)
@sync begin
    for (i,wpid) in enumerate(workers())
        @async begin
            remotecall_wait(wpid, myfunc, mat, combs[chunkbreaks[i]+1:chunkbreaks[i+1]])
        end
    end
end
```

where `myfunc` performs your calculation on the specified indexes of `mat`.

I should add, however, that unless your dissimilarity calculation is slow, serializing `combs` could make this slower than the single-threaded version. You could fix that by coming up with a much faster strategy for encoding the indexes assigned to each process (it could be encoded by just a `UnitRange{Int}` and using `divrem` to figure out the `i,j` indexes).

Comment: One thing to note is that myfunc() has to take the shared array and the list of (i,j) indeces as inputs, so it is not identical to f_dist().