# BLAS v. parallel updates for Julia SharedArray objects

Tags: parallel-processing, julia, blas

I am interested in using Julia `SharedArray`s for a scientific computing project. My current implementation appeals to BLAS for all matrix-vector operations, but I thought that perhaps a `SharedArray` would offer some speedup on multicore machines. My idea is to simply update an output vector index-by-index, farming the index updates to worker processes.

Previous discussions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874226/julia-efficient-parallelization-of-dissimilarity-matrix-computation?newreg=09c8f7716be143db9f21c0f337264711) about `SharedArray`s and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/julia-users/dxDz7JETsW4/FWbplJ_IrOwJ) about shared memory objects did not offer clear guidance on this issue. It seems intuitively simple enough, but after testing, I'm somewhat confused as to why this approach works so poorly (see code below). For starters, it seems like `@parallel for` allocates a lot of memory. And if I prefix the loop with `@sync`, which seems like a smart thing to do if the whole output vector is required later, then the parallel loop is substantially slower (though without `@sync`, the loop is mighty quick).

Have I incorrectly interpreted the proper use of the `SharedArray` object? Or perhaps did I inefficiently assign the calculations?

```
### test for speed gain w/ SharedArray vs. Array ###

# problem dimensions
n = 10000; p = 25000

# set BLAS threads; 64 seems reasonable in testing
blas_set_num_threads(64)

# make normal Arrays
x = randn(n,p)
y = ones(p)
z = zeros(n)

# make SharedArrays
X = convert(SharedArray{Float64,2}, x)  
Y = convert(SharedArray{Float64,1}, y)  
Z = convert(SharedArray{Float64,1}, z)  

# run BLAS.gemv! on Arrays twice, time second case
BLAS.gemv!('N', 1.0, x, y, 0.0, z)
@time BLAS.gemv!('N', 1.0, x, y, 0.0, z)

# does BLAS work equally well for SharedArrays? 
# check timing result and ensure same answer
BLAS.gemv!('N', 1.0, X, Y, 0.0, Z)
@time BLAS.gemv!('N', 1.0, X, Y, 0.0, Z)
println("$(isequal(z,Z))")  # should be true

# SharedArrays can be updated in parallel
# code a loop to farm updates to worker nodes
# use transposed X to place rows of X in columnar format
# should (hopefully) help with performance issues from stride
Xt = X'  
@parallel for i = 1:n 
    Z[i] = dot(Y, Xt[:,i])
end

# now time the synchronized copy of this
@time @sync @parallel for i = 1:n 
    Z[i] = dot(Y, Xt[:,i])
end

# still get same result?
println("$(isequal(z,Z))")  # should be true
```

Output from test with 4 workers + 1 master node:

```
elapsed time: 0.109010169 seconds (80 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.110858551 seconds (80 bytes allocated)
true
elapsed time: 1.726231048 seconds (119936 bytes allocated)
true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running into several issues, of which the most important is that `Xt[:,i]` creates a new array (allocating memory). Here's a demonstration that gets you closer to what you want:

```
n = 10000; p = 25000

# make normal Arrays
x = randn(n,p)
y = ones(p)
z = zeros(n)

# make SharedArrays
X = convert(SharedArray, x)  
Y = convert(SharedArray, y)  
Z = convert(SharedArray, z)

Xt = X'

@everywhere function dotcol(a, B, j)
    length(a) == size(B,1) || throw(DimensionMismatch("a and B must have the same number of rows"))
    s = 0.0
    @inbounds @simd for i = 1:length(a)
        s += a[i]*B[i,j]
    end
    s
end

function run1!(Z, Y, Xt)
    for j = 1:size(Xt, 2)
        Z[j] = dotcol(Y, Xt, j)
    end
    Z
end

function runp!(Z, Y, Xt)
    @sync @parallel for j = 1:size(Xt, 2)
        Z[j] = dotcol(Y, Xt, j)
    end
    Z
end

run1!(Z, Y, Xt)
runp!(Z, Y, Xt)
@time run1!(Z, Y, Xt)
zc = copy(sdata(Z))
fill!(Z, -1)
@time runp!(Z, Y, Xt)

@show sdata(Z) == zc
```

Results (when starting `julia -p 8`):

```
julia> include("/tmp/paralleldot.jl")
elapsed time: 0.465755791 seconds (80 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.076751406 seconds (282 kB allocated)
sdata(Z) == zc = true
```

For comparison, when running on this same machine:

```
julia> blas_set_num_threads(8)

julia> @time A_mul_B!(Z, X, Y);
elapsed time: 0.067611858 seconds (80 bytes allocated)
```

So the raw Julia implementation is at least competitive with BLAS.

Comment: ooh, I hadn't thought of the memory allocations for `Xt[:,i]`. And your example code is easy to follow. Thank you!

Comment: Why is `dotcol` faster when `B[i, j]` is used (as in your code) rather than `B[j, i]` (without requiring that the matrix `X` be transposed)?

Comment: @Taiki is this an issue of strided memory access? Julia stores arrays in column-major format. See the [documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/performance-tips/#access-arrays-in-memory-order-along-columns) for details.