# Julia parallel computing for loop

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I would like to calculate the summation of elements from a large upper triangular matrix. The regular Julia code is below.

```
function upsum(M); n = size(M)[1]; sum = 0
    for i = 1:n-1 for j = i+1:n
        sum = sum + M[i,j]
        end
    end
    return sum
end

R = randn(10000,10000)
upsum(R)
```

Since the matrix is very large, I would like to know is there anyway to improve the speed. How can I use parallel computing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Julia: efficient parallelization of dissimilarity matrix computation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874226/julia-efficient-parallelization-of-dissimilarity-matrix-computation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use threads not parallel processing in this case. Here is an example code:

```
using Base.Threads

function upsum_threads(M)
    n = size(M, 1)
    chunks = nthreads()
    sums = zeros(eltype(M), chunks)
    chunkend = round.(Int, n * sqrt.((1:chunks) ./ chunks))
    @assert minimum(diff(chunkend)) > 0
    chunkstart = [2; chunkend[1:end-1] .+ 1]
    @threads for job in 1:chunks
        s = zero(eltype(M))
        for i in chunkstart[job]:chunkend[job]
            @simd for j in 1:(i-1)
                @inbounds s += M[j, i]
            end
        end
        sums[job] = s
    end
    return sum(sums)
end

R = randn(10000,10000)
upsum_threads(R)
```

It should give you a significant speedup (even if you remove `@threads` it should be much faster).

You choose number of threads Julia uses by setting `JULIA_NUM_THREADS` environment variable.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! I have another question, what if I also want to calculate the summation of the square of each elements from the large upper triangular matrix at the same time. I tried `@inbounds s += M[j, i] @inbounds sq += M[j, i]^2`, it works. Is there any better way to do that?

Comment: It is probably better to have two inner loops than two operations in one inner loop as I think `@simd` should work then (but you have to benchmark if there is any significant difference between these two designs).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Do you mean it's better to have two `@threads for job in 1:chunks`.

Comment: I meant **inner** loop `@simd for j in 1:(i-1)`, as then `M[j,i]` should still be in CPU cache (but I have not benchmarked it so duplicating the **outermost** loop might not be significantly slower).